# Can a Node.js script read node options?

Tags: node.js

Is there a way for a script running in Node.js to read the options given when node was started, things like `-e`, `--max-old-space-size` or `--expose-gc`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes: These arguments are accessible via `process.execArgv`([docs](https://nodejs.org/api/process.html#process_process_execargv)).

Answer (score 0):

It has also a good set of app information available: `process.env`